# jQuery - How to determine between val and HTML?

Tags: jquery

Is there a way in jQuery to determine whether an element has a value or innerhtml (or both)? For example, if the element is input then it has a val and I can use:

```
$(this).val();
```

But if it's a div then I need to use:

```
$(this).html();
```

I need to know whether I have to use val or HTML. My piece of jQuery is:

```
$(".myclass").each(function(idx){
  if (this is a val based element)
    use val
  else
    use html
});
```

Comment: They represent very different pieces of data; in what context would you be iterating over those different element types and trying to get either the value or the inner HTML as content?

Comment: This is part of a generic function which does not know what element types it will be dealing with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.tagName` will tell you which element type you have. jQuery object doesn't have `tagName` property.

Comment: @Diodeus.. I think should be just this.tagName

Comment: I don't think the jQuery object has a tagName property.. http://jsfiddle.net/kY5HC/

Comment: Thank you - Seems this is my only option: if (this.tagName == "INPUT" || this.tagName == "BUTTON" || this.tagName...

Comment: This doesn't answer the asker's question. And like ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ said, jQuery doesn't have a `tagName` property. IMO, @A.Wolff's answer should be the one marked as correct.

Answer (score 5):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anderslyman/gyQyL/).

Html:

```
<div></div>
<input/>
<textarea></textarea>
<select>
    <option>foo</option>
    <option>baz</option>
</select>​
```

Code:

```
changeText("div", "baz");
changeText("input", "baz");
changeText("textarea", "baz");
changeText("select", "baz");

function changeText(selector, text) {
    var element = $(selector);
    var attr = element.attr('value');
    if (typeof attr !== 'undefined' && attr !== false) {
        element.val(text);
    } else {
        element.text(text);        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".myclass").each(function(k, v){
    var data = ($(v).val() ?: $(v).html());
});
```

Try to get data from .val(), if nothing was returned use .html().

Comment: What do you mean by nothing.  An input with nothing in it will still support the val option

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

[See DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KxPpe/)

```
$(".myclass").each(function(idx){
    if (this.hasOwnProperty('value'))
        //use val
    else
        //use html
});
```

Comment: This won't work for <button>s. Add `&& 'BUTTON' != this.tagName` to the condition in the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Check it has a value attribute

```
if ($(this).hasAttr('value')){



}
```

Comment: why -1? the val() will only take the value for the element from the value attribute. If it does not have a value attribute then you know to take the html or text()

Comment: It simply wont work on all elements, and there isn't even a .hasAttr() method.